# Check if an array contains any element of another array with some null in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a target array example: `["Potato", "Orange"]` . I'm making an api call that return an object with multiple array which I have to look if the array contain any one of the target array elements.

I have the following Piece of code, but I get following error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of null

I know this is because The object contains some Null values. How Can I fix this?

```
Example:    const myArray = [
   {
    Track: ["Potato", "Apple"],
           ["Banna"],
           ["Potato", "Batman", "Orange"]
     Type: ["Some", "Stuff"]
     },
   {
    Track: null
     Type: ["Some", "Stuff"]
     }
    ]

const value = "Potato"

const matchingSession = myArray.filter((obj) => value.some(x => { return obj.types.includes(x) || obj.tracks.includes(x)}));
```

Which it should Return :

```
[
["Potato", "Apple"],
["Potato", "Batman", "Orange"]
]
```

This is just an example. It could have more then one object in the array.

Comment: You do not have any properties anywhere named `types` (nor `tracks`). Your input also isn't valid Javascript, arrays cannot have key-value pairs

Comment: This has nothing to do with promises or Node.js. Unless your question is specifically _about_ those tags, please do not use them.

Comment: @CertainPerformance  Yes You are right sorry for my poorly example. I just edited, close to what I'm currently getting. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
myArray.filter((arr) => Array.isArray(arr) && arr.length > 0)
```

This line checks if the array object is a type of array and not empty

Read More about [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

## Edit

```
const arrayOfValues = ["Potato", "Apple"];
myArray.filter((arr) => {

    return Array.isArray(arr) && CheckArray(arrayOfValues, arr) && arr.length > 0
});
function CheckArray(Array, ArrayToCheck) {
    let found = false;
    for (const value of Array) {
        if (ArrayToCheck.includes(value)) {
            found = true;
        }
    }
    return found;
}
```

Checks if an array includes one of `arrayOfValues` and if the object is an array and not empty!

## Edit 2

```
const myArray = [
  {
    Track: ["Potato", "Apple"],
    data: [["Banna"],
      ["Potato", "Batman", "Orange"],
      ["Some", "Stuff"]],
  },
  {
    Tack: null,
    data: ["Some", "Stuff"],
  },
];
myArray.map((arr) => {
  return Array.isArray(arr.data) && CheckArray(arr.Track, arr.data);
}).filter(_ => !!_);

function CheckArray(arr, ArrayToCheck) {
  if (!arr || !Array.isArray(arr)) {
    return ArrayToCheck;
  }
  const foundArray = [];    
  if (ArrayToCheck.every(item => Array.isArray(item))) {
    for (const subArr of ArrayToCheck) {
      const ResultArray = CheckArray(arr, subArr);
      if (ResultArray.length > 0) {
        foundArray.push(ResultArray);
      }
    }
  } else {
    if (ArrayToCheck.map(val => arr.includes(val)).includes(true)) {
      foundArray.push(ArrayToCheck);
    }
  }
  return foundArray;
}
```

Checks if an `array` includes one of `Track` data, (works for sub-arrays (2d, etc..))

Comment: Thanks @JamalAbo I'll try this now! This is Great!

Comment: @Mandoxsy, ok, if it meets the requirements, don't forget to upvote and accept the answer!

Comment: will this code return a new array with matching element? or just bolean?

Comment: @Mandoxsy all codes return matched arrays, (and edit 2 -> for what meets `Track` requirements)